# Probability distribution for stopping a stopwatch on a multiple of 1s

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out the probability distribution for the following situation:

- start a stopwatch
- wait a random amount of time
- stop the stopwatch

A "success" is stopping the stopwatch on exactly a multiple of 1s, like 1s, 2s, 3s, etc. What would be the probability distribution or function that would describe this?

Comment: This is not clear.  What does "random" mean here?  Do you mean uniformly random on some time interval?  But in that case the probability of stopping on an integral number of seconds is $0$.  Of course, stopwatches only have finite precision (you can't measure billionths of a second with a conventional stopwatch, for example)...did you mean to take that into account?  If so, what degree of precision are we to assume?

Comment: Most stopwatches (take a look on Amazon, if you like) measure time in units of $0.01$ second, so the probability of stopping on a multiple of 1 second is $1/100$.

Comment: Assuming infinite precision, and that the random time could be any length of time. Thanks for your comments so far. Yes, this means the probability of stopping exactly on any given time is 0. But I'm thinking there is a probability distribution that describes this, like a Poisson distribution, for example.